# llama-cpp-python not using NVIDIA GPU CUDA

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, llama, llama-cpp-python

I have been playing around with [oobabooga text-generation-webui](https://github.com/oobabooga/text-generation-webui)  on my Ubuntu 20.04 with my NVIDIA GTX 1060 6GB for some weeks without problems. I have been using llama2-chat models sharing memory between my RAM and NVIDIA VRAM. I installed without much problems following the intructions on its repository.

So what I want now is to use the model loader `llama-cpp` with its package `llama-cpp-python` bindings to play around with it by myself. So using the same miniconda3 environment that oobabooga text-generation-webui uses I started a jupyter notebook and I could make inferences and everything is working well *BUT ONLY for CPU*.

A working example bellow,

```
from llama_cpp import Llama

llm = Llama(model_path="/mnt/LxData/llama.cpp/models/meta-llama2/llama-2-7b-chat/ggml-model-q4_0.bin", 
            n_gpu_layers=32, n_threads=6, n_ctx=3584, n_batch=521, verbose=True), 

prompt = """[INST] <<SYS>>
Name the planets in the solar system? 
<</SYS>>
[/INST] 
"""
output = llm(prompt, max_tokens=350, echo=True)
print(output['choices'][0]['text'].split('[/INST]')[-1])
```

> Of course! Here are the eight planets in our solar system, listed in order from closest to farthest from the Sun:
>
> 1. Mercury
> 2. Venus
> 3. Earth
> 4. Mars
> 5. Jupiter
> 6. Saturn
> 7. Uranus
> 8. Neptune

> Note that Pluto was previously considered a planet but is now classified as a dwarf planet due to its small size and unique orbit.

I want to make inference using GPU as well. What is wrong?
Why can't I offload to gpu like the parameter `n_gpu_layers=32` specifies and also like `oobabooga text-generation-webui` already does on the same miniconda environment whithout any problems?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After searching around and suffering quite for 3 weeks I found out this [issue](https://github.com/abetlen/llama-cpp-python/issues/509) of its repository.

So the `llama-cpp-python` needs to known where is the `libllama.so` shared library. So exporting it before running my python interpreter, jupyter notebook etc. did the trick.

For using the miniconda3 installation used by `oobabooga text-generation-webui` I exported it like bellow:

```
export LLAMA_CPP_LIB=/yourminicondapath/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_cpp_cuda/libllama.so
```

#### Voilà!!!!

On importing  `from llama_cpp import Llama` I get

> ggml_init_cublas: found 1 CUDA devices:
> Device 0: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060, compute capability 6.1

And on

```
llm = Llama(model_path="/mnt/LxData/llama.cpp/models/meta-llama2/llama-2-7b-chat/ggml-model-q4_0.bin", 
            n_gpu_layers=28, n_threads=6, n_ctx=3584, n_batch=521, verbose=True),
```

...

> llama_model_load_internal: using CUDA for GPU acceleration
> llama_model_load_internal: mem required  = 2381.32 MB (+ 1026.00 MB per state)
> llama_model_load_internal: allocating batch_size x (512 kB + n_ctx x 128 B) = 480 MB VRAM for the scratch buffer
> llama_model_load_internal: offloading 28 repeating layers to GPU
> llama_model_load_internal: offloaded 28/35 layers to GPU
> llama_model_load_internal: total VRAM used: 3521 MB
> ...

Answer (score 6):

I fixed the problem by making sure cuda toolkit was installed :

```
nvcc --version
```

If not, I installed cuda toolkit.

You should have access to CUDA_HOME after installing cuda toolkit:

```
echo $CUDA_HOME
```

Then reinstall llama-cpp :

```
CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_CUBLAS=on" pip install llama-cpp-python --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir
```

Comment: Well the OP states that oobabooga text-generation-webui  was working flawless with CUDA hence  it was properly installed but... let's let it here for those who come with OTHER questions.

Answer (score 2):

For folks looking for more detail on specific steps to take to enable GPU support for llama-cpp-python, you need to do the following:

1. Download cuda toolkit for your operating system (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)
2. Recompile llama-cpp-python with the appropriate environment variables set to point to your nvcc installation (included with cuda toolkit), and specify the cuda architecture to compile for. For example, if I had downloaded cuda-toolkit-12-3 in the step above and wanted to compile llama-cpp-python for all major cuda architectures, I would run:

   ```
   CUDACXX=/usr/local/cuda-12/bin/nvcc CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_CUBLAS=on
   -DCMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES=all-major" FORCE_CMAKE=1 pip install llama-cpp-python --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall --upgrade
   ```

Other valid values for `CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES` are `all` (for all) or `native` to build for the host system's GPU architecture. (Note that GPUs are usually not available while building a container image, so avoid using `-DCMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES=native` in a Dockerfile unless you know what you're doing)

Here's a Dockerfile that shows an example of the steps above. It uses a Debian base image (python:3.10-bookworm), downloads and installs the appropriate cuda toolkit for the OS, and compiles llama-cpp-python with cuda support (along with jupyterlab):

```
FROM python:3.10-bookworm

## Add your own requirements.txt if desired and uncomment the two lines below
# COPY ./requirements.txt .

# RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

## Install CUDA Toolkit (Includes drivers and SDK needed for building llama-cpp-python with CUDA support)
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
    wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.3.1/local_installers/cuda-repo-debian12-12-3-local_12.3.1-545.23.08-1_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i cuda-repo-debian12-12-3-local_12.3.1-545.23.08-1_amd64.deb && \
    cp /var/cuda-repo-debian12-12-3-local/cuda-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/ && \
    add-apt-repository contrib && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install cuda-toolkit-12-3 

#Install llama-cpp-python with CUDA Support (and jupyterlab)
RUN CUDACXX=/usr/local/cuda-12/bin/nvcc CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_CUBLAS=on -DCMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES=all-major" FORCE_CMAKE=1 \
    pip install jupyterlab llama-cpp-python --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall --upgrade

WORKDIR /workspace

CMD ["jupyter", "lab", "--ip", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8888", "--NotebookApp.token=''", "--NotebookApp.password=''", "--no-browser", "--allow-root"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ryan's answer helped me with the solution for this problem on Windows 11 and PowerShell:

```
$env:CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_CUBLAS=on"
$env:CUDACXX="C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.2\bin\nvcc.exe"
pip install llama-cpp-python[server] --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir
```

Needless to say, replace the path to nvcc.exe with whatever is on your machine.

And remove `[server]` if you don't want it.