# Llama 2 Local AI using CPU instead of GPU - i5 10th Gen, RTX 3060 Ti, 48GB RAM

Tags: python, gpu, artificial-intelligence, cpu, llama

I have a setup with an Intel i5 10th Gen processor, an NVIDIA RTX 3060 Ti GPU, and 48GB of RAM running at 3200MHz, Windows 11. I recently downloaded the LLama 2 model from TheBloke, but it seems like the AI is utilizing my CPU instead of my GPU.

Is there a configuration or setting I need to change to make LLama 2 Local AI use my GPU for processing instead of my CPU? I want to take full advantage of my GPU's capabilities for better performance.

Some answers given by the AI were out of place, and as if it was crazy or the AI cut itself in the middle of an answer.

Any guidance or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import warnings
from llama_cpp import Llama

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# Initialize the speech recognition recognizer
recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

# Initialize the text-to-speech engine
engine = pyttsx3.init()

# Initialize the wake-up word and sleep mode word
wake_up_word = "assistant"
sleep_mode_word = "mute"

# Load the large language model file
LLM = Llama(model_path="D:\VoiceAssisant\llama-2-13b-chat.Q6_K.gguf", f16_kv=True)

# Create a function to listen for the wake-up word and start listening for user input
def listen():
    asleep = True  # Initialize sleep mode state

    while True:
        print("Listening for wake up word...")
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            audio = recognizer.listen(source)
            try:
                text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
                if text.lower() == wake_up_word:
                    print("Listening for query...")
                    asleep = False  # Exit sleep mode
                    while True:
                        with sr.Microphone() as source:
                            audio = recognizer.listen(source)
                            try:
                                input_text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
                                if input_text.lower() == sleep_mode_word:
                                    print("Sleep mode activated...")
                                    asleep = True  # Enter sleep mode
                                    break
                                else:
                                    prompt = "Q: " + input_text + " A:"
                                    output = LLM(prompt, max_tokens=256, stop=["Q:", "\n"], echo=True)
                                    response_text = output["choices"][0]["text"]
                                    print(response_text)
                                    engine.say(response_text)
                                    engine.runAndWait()
                            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                                pass
                elif text.lower() == sleep_mode_word:
                    print("Sleep mode activated...")
                    asleep = True  # Enter sleep mode
            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                pass

# Start listening for the wake-up word
listen()
```

I have tried installing some programs by Nvidia but it seems that the one I wanted to install was only available for Linux.

Comment: Possibly similar (but Ubuntu rather than Windows) [llama-cpp-python not using NVIDIA GPU CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76963311/llama-cpp-python-not-using-nvidia-gpu-cuda)

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you start by getting llama.cpp to work as a command line tool. If you have that going, _then_ you're in a good place to try to configure the Python bindings to have identical behavior (with the question narrowly focused on the bindings themselves, with the larger hardware/OS/&c questions safely out of scope). Right now this is posed in such a way that we can't rule out causes that aren't development-specific, arguably making the question too broad to be on topic.

Answer (score 1):

Most Nvidia 3060Ti GPU's have only 8GB VRAM. [Your chosen model](https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/Llama-2-13B-chat-GGUF) "llama-2-13b-chat.Q6_K.gguf" with 10.68 GB size and 13.18 GB max RAM requirements doesn't fit to VRAM of your GPU.
Try to use smaller model, like "llama-2-13b-chat.Q2_K.gguf" with 5.43 GB size and 7.93 GB max RAM requirements.